# Washing machine will not start the drain process

Tags: washing-machine

I select a program then hit Start, but the program does not begin. No noise, no beeps, just sits doing nothing.

I put the machine into diagnostics mode and ran through the tests. Everything works fine in diagnostics mode except for drain. The drain pumps do not even start - not even the least noise from it.

I took out the twin drain pumps (this is a Samsung WF90F5E5U4X "Eco Bubble") and checked them thoroughly, and the resistance of the windings was fine on both pumps and within a few ohms difference between the two pumps.

What would the next things to test?

Comment: Do the pumps actually spin freely by hand? The motors might work but the bearings might be shot.

Comment: The drain pump motors spin by hand, and have the usual magnetic cogging effect as you turn the impellor.

Comment: Test the START button.

Comment: @MTA when it diagnostic mode - which doesn't use the start button - it also fails to drain.